# Merge consumes far too much memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to perform what I think is a very simple operation in Pandas, which is merging 3 dataframes.

Before we even get into other tools, I have tried Polars, I have tried R data.table, I have tried Dask, I have even tried doing gc.collect() before the second merge. I have tried most solutions I could find on Stackoverflow to no avail.  I cannot wrap my head around how this runs out of memory in each instance.

I create 3 dataframes from TSV files that, in total, add up to less than 2GB of space.  I am dropping multiple columns from each file, and am doing a simple inner join on the three dataframes, how can this use 64 GB+ of RAM every single time?

When I create the first 3 data frames and drop extraneous columns, I have used 18 GB of my memory according to `free -h`, and have 40GB left over.

`dfcombined = df1.merge(df2, left_on="key1", right_on="key2", how="inner")`

After this I also run `del df1, df2; gc.collect()`.

This merge of the two largest data frames is successful and at this point I am going from 40GB of free memory to 38GB free.  But for some reason when I try to join this third (and smallest) dataframe...

`combine = dfcombined.merge(df3, left_on="key1", right_on="key3", how="inner")`

I continually get an OOM error.  I assume this may have something to do with how these data frames pass by reference to the original dataframes? I really am stumped and I have been at this for several hours.

The shape of `dfcombined` is `(20786437, 32)` and the shape of df3 is `(2370993, 5)`.  There are many matches for `df3` and `dfcombined`, but there should not be so many that it takes up 64GB.

The dtype is also probably very expensive in that I would make most columns a string.

`df3` looks like (all fields need to be strings, last field is not a number):

```
index key1 field1 field2 field3 field4 field4
0 "ID1" "A string value" "S" "2" "n/a"
1 "ID1" "Another string" "R" "1" "7/2"
2 "ID1" "New string" "R" "1" "7/2"
3 "ID2" "First string value" "R" "1" "7/2"
```

`dfcombined` has many string columns of a similar nature, the first 74 rows have the the same `key1`, so there is a many-to-many join here.  This could explain the merge size blow-up, but to such an extent?

Edit 1:
After speaking with @chrslg, I should say there are `1151147` unique keys in `dfcombine` and `139162` in `df3` and the OOM error is looking less like a hypothesis and more like a fact now.  Refer to our chat [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250247/discussion-between-jimh-and-chrslg).

Comment: Are you deleting df1, df2 and df3 as soon as possible? They will continue to hold resources until you do.

Comment: Sounds to me like the dataframe you're trying to create is just way bigger than you were expecting it to be, especially if you ran out of memory on all those not-Pandas ways of doing this too.

Comment: @tdelaney yes I have done this.  `del df1, df2; gc.collect()`

Comment: Hard to say anything with so few information tho. What are the shape of involved dataframes (dfcombined and df3 importantly). A few lines of those, etc.

Comment: @chrslg I'll update my question.

Comment: @user2357112 but to this extent with the shape information provided?  are there any other things I could be doing wrong code-wise?

Comment: Repetion of keys is probably the problem here, indeed. Extrapolating from the only example I can state: you have 8.7 times more rows in dfcombined than in df3. That 's a lot. But you have 74 repetitions of its keys (for the 1st one, at least). And only 3 repetitions in df3. And 74/3 is > 8.7. So, my point is, I have no reason to think that most of dfcombined rows are unmatched. And if they are all matched by 3 rows of df3 (which is conservative... again, you seem to have less keys than that, so more match per keys), then combine would be more than 3 times bigger than dfconbine

Comment: Which is enougth to oom. And that are very rough, but rather conservative approximation. How many unique keys to you have in those 2 dataframes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250247/discussion-between-jimh-and-chrslg).

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with @chrslg in the chat linked above, I decided to go with using `dfcombine` separately from `df3` (and even `df1` and `df2` by themselves in some cases).  The precompute from having it all in memory would have been nice, but it was ultimately easier to avoid OOM and use `pd.DataFrame.apply()` and `dfcombine[dfcombine["field3"] == "some value"]` as a filter.

Treating it like SQL and performing what amounts to SELECT queries like this, and *then* performing JOINs is most likely best practice. I'm happy to leave this open if someone finds a different workaround, but this was the answer I came to, ultimately.